# Consecutive suggested edits on the same post by the same user

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

A user [suggests an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3466705) which gets rejected as being too minor. 7 minutes later the same edit gets [re-suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3466736) by the same user on the same post and gets approved.

So actually this means that someone can repeatedly re-suggest the same edit until it bumps into a set 5 reviewers, from which the 3 of them will approve it. **Wouldn't it make more sense if, after having a suggested edit being rejected on post, lose the right to edit this post again (at least for a time period)?**

I know that this isn't really important and adding too much complexity in the system just for these rare occasions is not a good idea, but nevertheless it's worth to give it a quick thought :)

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but this would prevent people from providing a *better* suggestion also. Perhaps, allow edits but put them under special scrutiny somehow? Like show a message to reviewers?

Comment: The problem is reviewers and reviewing correctly rather than the suggested edit. A better way would be to inform reviewers like probablyPekka suggests.

Comment: Indeed looks like a dup, I didn't seen this when I searched before posting. Should I delete my question, or keep it since the other one doesn't have an accepted answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The desire to do this is understandable - but it would prevent people from providing a *better* suggestion, too. Perhaps allow edits but put them under special scrutiny somehow?

Like show a message to reviewers:

> This user has previously suggested an edit to this question that was rejected. 
>   Please review with extra care.

Answer (score 4):

Like you said this sort of behavior is rare, you may want to just flag one of the user's posts and explain to a moderator what you're seeing, rather than altering the system to deal with an edge case.

Something like:

[image]

Comment: ^^^^ This. The moderators will then contact the user privately and ask them to stop, in most cases.

Comment: Good suggestion although instead of escalating the problem to the mods, an automatic solution or an information like Pekka's suggestion would still be preferable. My only concern with your approach, is that I actually have to flag the post and not suggested edit, which is a little bit awkward if the post is a good one. And I'm not sure if you too realized that, because in your screenshot you are saying "link to post" and not "link to edit"! @Tiny Tim do moderators have immediate access to all suggested edits in a post, even the rejected ones? Or do I have include the links to suggested edits?

Comment: @psxls I would guess that linking to the suggested edit would be a good idea, but you can't flag suggested edits, so you would have to place the flag on the post in question or on one of the offending user's posts.