# Consecutive _good_ suggested edits on the same post by the same user

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

Is it okay for one user to suggest multiple consecutive edits?

Assuming:

- Both (or all) of the edits are *good* suggestions.
- They were all suggested within a short enough time period that the first edit probably hasn't been reviewed at all.

Is there a limit to how many (good) suggested edits can or *should* be submitted within, say, a few minutes?

I don't know what the suggested edits review queue UI looks like for multiple suggested edits. Are the multiple edits combined into one set of changes to review? Do reviewers have to review each edit separately?

---

This *isn't* identical to this question:

- [Consecutive suggested edits on the same post by the same user - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209310/consecutive-suggested-edits-on-the-same-post-by-the-same-user)

The first paragraph of that question:

> A user suggests an edit which gets rejected as being too minor. 7 minutes later the same edit gets re-suggested by the same user on the same post and gets approved.

I also didn't see this covered in this suggested edits super-question:

- [How do suggested edits work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Comment: If your initial edit isn't approved/rejected yet, the subsequent ones will be merged with it. So, don't worry about it.

Comment: @41686d6564 – Thanks! Add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. I just made a 'second consecutive suggested edit on another question and that's what it _seems_ like happened AFAICT.

Comment: @KennyEvitt No need to. I found a duplicate: [Can I modify and resubmit my suggested edit before it is peer reviewed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157601/can-i-modify-and-resubmit-my-suggested-edit-before-it-is-peer-reviewed)

Comment: @41686d6564 Nice find! I just voted to close this question (my own question!) as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: In the Reopen queue it shows multiple attempts in a table above the question, but I don't have a screenshot; whether that's coming to other queues such as Suggested Edits remains to be seen.

Comment: @Rob I don't understand your comment – there were multiple attempts to re-open this question? It's fine that it's closed – it _is_ a duplicate. I just hadn't found the 'original' before I asked this one.

Comment: @Kenny, that's [not what I wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369164/consecutive-good-suggested-edits-on-the-same-post-by-the-same-user?noredirect=1#comment1231778_369164).

Comment: @Rob I think you linked to _my_ comment in your last comment. I'm not sure why you did that. Anyways, I'm still confused about your first comment on this. Why did you mention the "Reopen queue"? Did you mean that, in the re-open queue, you can see multiple _edits_ ("attempts")?

Comment: Kenny, yes . . .

Comment: `"I  don't know what the suggested edits review queue UI looks like for multiple suggested edits. Are the multiple edits combined into one set of changes to review? Do reviewers have to review each edit separately?"` --- Only one can be pending in the Suggested Edits queue, once the question enters a different queue and has multiple edits prior to reopening it looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhhL.png); that's where it shows up.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the screenshot! Those multiple edits are for different users tho.

Comment: Kenny, yes. It will take weeks to try to find one, that's as good an example as is available; and I probably won't be coming back here in a month or two with another, so it will have to do. 

Comment: @Rob Yes, sorry – didn't mean to imply that you _owed_ me, or anyone, a 'better screenshot'. I'm writing my comments with the 'general audience' in mind. I appreciate the extra info you've shared!

Comment: I didn't take it that way. The ideal situation would be that someone spots this and has exactly what you need.